# UIPicker With View + View Tapped != Selected Row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uipicker

Hey!  I have a UIPicker, and I am using the function:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
```

But, when you tap one of the views returned by this function, the tapped view does not become highlighed, and selected if the touch is released.  How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of this property,

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

at initialization.